# Android SQLite issue: 'Table [...] has no column named' error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I keep getting error that a column in my table cannot be found. Cannot figure out why this is happening. The column names appear to be spelled correctly.

I'm getting this error : 
`06-11 21:27:02.701    3703-3703/com.example.luca.contatti E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table Contatti has no column named imageUri`

**This is my DatabaseHandler page:**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "dbContatti",
        TABLE = "Contatti",
        ID = "id",
        NAME = "name",
        PHONE = "phone",
        EMAIL = "email",
        ADDRESS = "address",
        IMAGEURI = "imageUri";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 4;

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //Creazione della tabella per il DB
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + NAME + "TEXT," + PHONE + "TEXT," + EMAIL + "TEXT," + ADDRESS + "TEXT," + IMAGEURI + "TEXT " + ")");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);

    onCreate(db);
}

// CRUD: CREATE

public void createContact (ContactList contact){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(PHONE, contact.getPhone());
    values.put(EMAIL, contact.getEmail());
    values.put(ADDRESS, contact.getAddress());
    values.put(IMAGEURI, contact.getImageUri().toString());

    db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();
}

//CRUD: READ

public ContactList getContact(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, new String[] {ID, NAME, PHONE, EMAIL, ADDRESS, /*IMAGEURI*/}, ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null,null );

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    ContactList contact = new ContactList(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(5)));
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return contact;
}

//CRUD: UPDATE

public int updateContact(ContactList contact){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(PHONE, contact.getPhone());
    values.put(EMAIL, contact.getEmail());
    values.put(ADDRESS, contact.getAddress());
    values.put(IMAGEURI, contact.getImageUri().toString());

    return db.update(TABLE, values, ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getId()) });
}

//CRUD: DELETE

public void deleteContact(ContactList contact){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    db.delete(TABLE, ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(contact.getId())});
    db.close();
}

public int getContactsCount(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return count;
}

public List<ContactList> getAllContacts(){
    List<ContactList> contacts = new ArrayList<ContactList>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            ContactList contact = new ContactList(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(5)));
            contacts.add(contact);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return contacts;
}
}
```

Also when i remove this statement:

```
values.put(IMAGEURI, contact.getImageUri().toString());
```

I've problem with other statements.

What can i do for fix this problem? Please help me!!

Comment: If you have added ImageUri some time later, you may need to immigrate your database. So try uninstalling your app and install again.

Comment: I've alrady unistalling my app but the reult is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have to put whitespaces between each column names and their type :

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + NAME + " TEXT," + PHONE + " TEXT," + EMAIL + " TEXT," + ADDRESS + " TEXT," + IMAGEURI + " TEXT " + ")");
```

Second, in your Cursor :

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, new String[] {ID, NAME, PHONE, EMAIL, ADDRESS, /*IMAGEURI*/}, ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null,null );
```

you wrote `/*IMAGEURI*/` ! So it's normal that some lines later, the `cursor.getString(5)` doesn't exist, and it crashes too :

```
ContactList contact = new ContactList(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(5)));
```

Finally make sure your Datamodel is updated. 
If you just added the imageUri column while the database has been created during previous debug sessions, it will crash. You well overrided `onUpgrade` method to delete existing tables, but I hope you didn't forget to increment Database version value too ;-)

Comment: I tried to 'clear data' on my emulator and unistalled my app from the emulator but the result didn't change. Every times that i run my application i manually change the data version of the DB. i don't understand how to fix this..  What else I can do?

Comment: did you make code modifications I advised you to do, first ?

Comment: I uncommented IMAGEURI and i overrided the onUpgrade method. I don't undersand if i run the application the DB should be deleted by the method onUpgrade and recreated with the right number of column or not??

Comment: And if I unistalling and reinstalling android studio and i start a new project and after this i copy manually the code, i can fix this problem?

Comment: No, your DB is not automatically deleted by onUpgrade !
You have to "+1" your `DB_VERSION` int first
And installing/reinstalling Android studio for such a kind of bug is absolutely overkill and useless ;-)

Comment: Thanks @PAD finally this morning i solved the problem.. Thanks!! :)

Comment: You're welcome ;-) Don't forget to "validate" the answer if it helped you